# shutdown script of weblogic manged server gracefully

Tags: weblogic, shutdown

Looking all over the internet to use **wlst** to shutdown weblogic managed servers gracefully (not from admin console)

Comment: Simple google search shows this:
`shutdown('managed_server', 'Server', force="false")`

Comment: Thanks I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

1. Run $WL_HOME/common/bin/wlst.sh
2. Connect to admin server with your credentionals
   **wls:/offline> connect('weblogic','password','t3://localhost:7001')**
3. To start managed server use

   **start('PROD_Server01','Server')**
4. To stop managed server use

   **shutdown('PROD_Server01','Server')**

Comment: Thanks I will try. And this does graceful?